# Index of free group of rank $k$ in free group of rank $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

I thought about the following question

> What is the index of the free group of rank $k$, denoted $F_k$, in the free group of rank $n$, denoted $F_n$?

Let's say for the moment, $k < n$, and say $[F_n:F_k] = i$. Then by Nielsen-Schreier's theorem, and by the fact that $F_k$ is a subgroup of $F_n$, we have that $F_k$ must be isomorphic to $F_{i(n-1)+1}$. Thus we must have
$$k = i(n-1)+1 \iff i = \frac{k-1}{n-1}.$$

So if, for example, we set $n = 7$ and $k = 4$, we must have $i = \frac{3}{6} = \frac{1}{2}$.

To me, this $\frac{1}{2}$ does not make sense at all, I was expecting an integer. What is wrong with the above?

I also have another question. I know that $F_n$ is a subgroup of $F_2$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but is it true that $F_n$ is a subgroup of $F_k$, for $k > 2$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and in particular when $n > k$?

Comment: It just means that $F_4$ does not occur as a subgroup of finite index in $F_7$. But it does occur as a subgroup of infinite index. The Nielsen-Schreier Theorem only applies to finite index subgroups.  In fact $F_k$ is a subgroup of $F_n$ for every $k \ge 0$ and every $n > 1$, but sometimes only as a subgroup of infinite index.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how it occurs as a subgroup of infinite index please? It is the part I am having troubles to understand. Also do you have a reference for the fact that $F_k$ is a subgroup of $F_n$ for every $k \geq 0$ and $n >1$? Last question, to come back on $F_4$ and $F_7$, now that I know that $F_7$ is a subgroup of $F_4$, would that mean by Nielsen-Schreier's theorem that $[F_4:F_7]=2$, because $7 = 2  \cdot (4-1) + 1$?

Comment: I think it is obvious that $F_4$ is a subgroup of $F_7$ and since, by the N.S. theorem it cannot have finite index, it must have infinite index. You don't need a reference for $F_k$ being a subgroup of $F_n$ it follows easily from $F_n$ being a subgroup of $F_2$ for all $n$. Yes $F_7$ is a subgroup of $F_4$ of index $2$. But it also occurs as a subgroup of infinite index in $F_4$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you for your clarifications. Regarding your last sentence, did you write what you meant? Because in that case I don't understand how $F_7$ is a subgroup of index $2$ in $F_4$, and at the same time be a subgroup of infinite index in $F_4$.

Comment: There are many (countably many) subgroups isomorphic to $F_7$ as subgroups of $F_4$. When $F_7$ occurs as a finite index subgroup of $F_4$ it has index 2 by N.S., but that does not mean it only occurs as an index 2 subgroup, since it can happen to be infinite index (pick your favorite infinite index subgroup, then choose a subgroup of that isomorphic to $F_7$...)

Comment: (and your favorite infinite index subgroup is not cyclic ;) )

Comment: @PaulPlummer I guess you refer to the fact that if $K < H < G$, then $[G:K]=[G:H][H:K]$. So if we set $G=F_4$, $H=F_3$ and $K=F_7$ we have that $[G:H] = \infty$ by N-S and $[H:K] = \infty$ by N-S, thus $[G:K] = \infty \cdot \infty = \infty$. If I understood correctly, this is so weird to me.

Comment: Not sure what you find weird about it.

Comment: @PaulPlummer I think it's because I've almost only worked with finite groups, thus Lagrange's theorem was holding and if $H<G$, then $[G:H] = |G|/|H|$ and thus the index is unique.

Comment: I guess that can be a little jarring, but it should become about as surprising as the the natural numbers have the same cardinality as the even numbers, or that the natural numbers can be split into countably many disjoint countable sets (and each of those could too, and so on). Infinite objects don't behave like finite objects, a lot of the time (and we often look for properties that make an object "seem more finite", like compactness and ascending/descending chain conditions etc)